# mysql sum function not giving results

Tags: php, mysql

I am a bit confused in calculating sum of particular column using mysql.

Database Structure
table name: personal
there is 25 rows in total, and columns id, userid, name and amount.

I want to calculate amount of particular userid through running session.

Code:

```
<?php
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$sql = "SELECT userid, SUM(amount) FROM personal";
echo $sql."<br/>";
echo $userid;
?>
```

Output:
SELECT userid, SUM(amount) FROM personal
gold99

Please help..guys..

Comment: I don't know php but your query is wrong. To select the `SUM(amount)` for a specific user you should do `select sum(amount) from personal where userid = <your user id>`. I am not sure how to bind variables in php but I think you should go in this direction.

Comment: also - in the code snippet you shared there's no connection to the db and execution of the sql.. maybe this will help [http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As you have written it you will get one arbitrary user name, followed by the sum of all amounts. If you want the sum for each user name you need to use SUM as an aggregate function with a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT userid, sum(amount) FROM personal GROUP BY userid
```

and as mentioned if you want the sum for just one user, use a WHERE clause.
But getting the query right is only part of the problem. You also need to use php functions to execute that query against some database. This is normally done either with mysqli_ APIs or PDO (more object-y and works against various database providers). 
You'll need to access a database, create a statement, execute it, and fetch the results. See http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and  http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php for more, and give it a try on your own.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $sql = "SELECT userid, SUM(amount) as amount FROM personal where userid=$userid";
    //echo $sql."<br/>";

    //you must execute query
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    $result=mysql_fetch_array($query);

    echo $result['amount'];
    ?>
```

Comment: DO NOT use mysql APIs, as they are deprecated. Use mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: Error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given line no 50

Comment: Line 50:- $result=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

Comment: it must happen sometime sql is wrong  uncomment echo $sql. and run  copy select statement into your phpmyadmin and check query is correct

Comment: it is the error ? please show your table cloums.mysql is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Query it will work :**

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amount FROM personal WHERE userid='xyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT userid,amount, SUM(amount) FROM personal WHERE sponserid='$_SESSION[userid]'"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysqli_error($conn)))
{
    echo "UserId:". "=". $row['userid'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Amount of Id". "=". $row['amount'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Sum of total Income"."=".$row['SUM(amount)'];


$i++;   } ?>
```

Comment: This won't work properly, so I'll assume that you meant to add this snippet to your question as an edit instead of answering.